# How GET works with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have an `AJAX` pagination that is working, actually it does not work better, I'm trying to understand how `AJAX` works with the url for pagination to work correctly.

What happens is that in normal pagination, without AJAX each of the links worked normal, more specifically the prev and the next: `prev 1 2 3 4 next`, since the `GET` was in the same url.

But with `AJAX` only the sequence of numbers works. If I put `$next = $current_page + 1;` the `$current_page` variable always receives the current url without the value of `$_GET["page_no"]` then with `AJAX` if I'm on page 8 and click next on pagination, apparently not recognizing the GET in the current url, the next goes to page 1 instead of page 9.

I do not know if this has to do with working with `date-haref`, rather than `href`.

Thanks

**class.crud.php**

```
public function paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
{

    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($total_no_of_records > 0)
    {
        ?><ul class="pagination"><?php
        $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);
        $current_page=1;
        if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
        {
            $current_page=$_GET["page_no"];
        }
        if($current_page!=1)
        {
            $previous =$current_page-1;
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=1'>First</a></li>";
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$previous."'>Back</a></li>";

        }
        for($i=1;$i<=$total_no_of_pages;$i++)
        {
            if($i==$current_page)
            {
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."' style='color:red;'>".$i."</a></li>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<li class='page-item'><ahref='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
            }
        }
        if($current_page!=$total_no_of_pages)
        {
            $next=$current_page+1;
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$next."'>Next</a></li>";
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$total_no_of_pages."'>Last</a></li>";
        }
        ?></ul><?php
    }
}
```

**AJAX**

```
$('.page-link').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var url = $(this).data('href');

   $.ajax({
         url: url,
         success: function (response) {

           var html = $('<h1/>', {html : response}).find('#paginacao-ajax');
           $('#paginacao-ajax').html( html )              

         }
   });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you do the AJAX call you need to add the current page number onto the URL as a query variable, so that it becomes something like:

```
http://my-server.domain/path?page_no=4
```

That last bit is what is picked up by the $_GET in PHP. So in javascript you'll need some way to detect the current page number and add it onto the clicked URL.

P.S. I recommend using a library like URIJS to manipulate URLS, rather than just pasting it onto the end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but then I will rewrite the php urls with .htacess

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Method GET

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: "GET",
     success: function (response) {
       var html = $('<h1/>', {html : response}).find('#paginacao-ajax');
       $('#paginacao-ajax').html( html )              
     }
});
```